# Can't paste multiple lines in latest iPython

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I am using the latest ipython 5.1 and python 3, but have trouble in directly pasting multiple lines to the command line. I am working on CentOs.

Can somebody try pasting the Duck class on the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and see whether you can get any error:

```
class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The duck has white and gray feathers.")
```

All these are properly indented and can be pasted into my .py file and run fine. But when I paste it to iPython, I always receive this error:

```
In [8]: class Duck:
   ...:         def quack(self):
   ...:                 print("Quaaaaaack!")
   ...:             def feathers(self):
  File "<ipython-input-8-aca228a732db>", line 4
    def feathers(self):
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

EDITTED:

Both my %paste and %cpaste don't work. I have installed the Tinker library, as seen below:

```
[abigail@localhost my_env]$ rpm -q tkinter
tkinter-2.7.5-39.el7_2.x86_64
```

But %paste always displays an error:

```
In [10]: %paste
ERROR:root:Getting text from the clipboard on this platform requires Tkinter.
```

%cpaste doesn't work either, it doesn't print anything to the screen:

```
In [8]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:--

In [9]:
```

EDITTED:

```
[abigail@localhost my_env]$ sudo yum install python3-tk
[sudo] password for abigail: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.web-ster.com
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirror.supremebytes.com
No package python3-tk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

python3-tk not available on CentOS 7?

Comment: Use %paste or %cpaste magic.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, please see more info.

Comment: @user697911 did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

For using `%paste` you need to install python3-tk. And I guess you misunderstood how `%cpaste` works. Run it, paste your code, press Enter, enter `--`, press Enter again.

Comment: Please see my update: No package python3-tk available.

Comment: Show me the output of `which python3` and `which ipython`. Did you installed them from rpm?

Comment: I am on CentOS, and it turns out that the command is "sudo yum install -y python3-tkinter", while on Ubutu it is "sudo yum install -y python3-tk". I had been trying using the latter.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?s=6139999b6b0449fdeccca352a4bca3c8&t=289095&page=2) can help.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `%cpaste`, you have to type `%cpaste`, then `ctrl+shift+v` to paste, then type `--` and then `enter` to exit the pasted text screen. Any `stdout` should appear after this.

Example:

```
In [2]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The duck has white and gray feathers.")::::
:--

In [3]: d = Duck()

In [4]: d.quack()
Quaaaaaack!
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is possible set a handy shortcut using `%alias_magic`  magic command

Type `%alias_magic -l p paste`

From now on, copy the desired lines to clipboard and simply press `p <Enter>`

I've tested with your class. it works as a charm.

```
class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The duck has white and gray feathers.")
```

After

```
 in [18]:d = Duck()
 in [19]:d.quack()
 Quaaaaaaaack
```